# Google Earth, Google satellite, and Bing aerial accuracy

Tags: google-earth, bing-maps, accuracy

Does anybody know the accuracy of Google Earth, Google satellite, and Bing aerials, and at what scale? I think that you have different/better accuracy if you have subscribed to their professional version.

Comment: from what I know, you don't have different accuracy with their professionnal version. Just more tools. The accuracy varies depending on your loacation

Comment: what do you mean depends on your location, I think in google earth you have sth about 25 meters accuracy in general and I also think that there are some standards about horizontal accuracy and map scale but I don't know for the specific maps I referred to

Answer (score 7):

Both Google Earth and Bing map use data from different sources (satellite images and ortho-photos). The horizontal accuracy depends on the source of the datasets and the level of orthorectification. It is usually better near cities than "in the middle of nowhere", but it primarily depends on the data sources. For instance, some countries have agreements with those image providers to use their national ortho-photo basemaps. In this case, the geolocation accuracy can be as good as one meter (or even better). In other places, images are adjusted based on co-registration with reference data (e.g. Landsat composite) so that the accuracy is worse than 25 m. There were noticeable improvements of the geolocation accuracy since the first launch of those products, but I still found errors up to 50 meters last year in some remote areas (in Brazil and in Africa).

Comment: @radouxju Do you happen to know if their is any documentation on which sources they specifically use?